# Is there a way to order SQL data by closeness to a specific number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I'm writing a query in which it needs to show names of certain trucks from the closest to the users latitude longitude location to the furthest away, ive been searching for a specific query to do this and have been getting dead ends

```
SELECT * FROM PrivateBookings
INNER JOIN Truck ON Truck.truck_id=PrivateBookings.Food_truck 
ORDER BY (closeness to $lat), (closeness to $lon)";
```

I have been doing a bit of reasearch, i may have not been using the right key words but i can't find anything relating to my issue

Comment: If you use a `geometry` or `geography` data type you'll be able to work out the distance between those 2 points, and then you can order by that.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help immensely. Sounds like `ORDER BY someGeographyPoint.STDistance(...` is what you want

Comment: @Red Dog1525 You tagged MySQL but from `sqlsrv_query` looks like you are using SQL Server? Can you confirm?

Comment: [This](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/) may help you.